# Jira Confluence Integration with Jenkins

Tags: plugins, hudson, jenkins, jira

I was able configure Jira confluence in the global configuration page of Jenkins, however I am not able to follow quitely how to use in the job specif configuration page.

Publish to Confluence
    Confluence Site

```
Space   What should I give? 
Page    What is the input?  

How to use Markup wiki, Please advise.
```

Answer (score 1):

Extract from from https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Confluence+Publisher+Plugin

> With at least one site configured, enable the "Publish to Confluence"
>   post-build action, and select from one of the pre-configured
>   Confluence sites. Enter the Space and Page name where the attachment
>   should end up (e.g., for this URL
>   (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Confluence+Publisher+Plugin),
>   Space name = "JENKINS", Page name = "Confluence+Publisher+Plugin").
>
> If you have enabled "Archive the artifacts", and wish to automatically
>   upload everything that was archived, check the box labeled "Attach
>   archived artifacts to page". Otherwise, enter an Ant-style fileset
>   pattern to specify which files should be uploaded.

Comment: Thanks Daria, but was able to successfully connect to confluence page, but can you give me example what to display , in the page, I basically might need clover report,checkstyle and warnings report and recent changes in the build.or All changes.
  Wiki Markup Replacements 
Append content

  Content generator: 
File contents
Plain text
  Text Content